# How do I sort list with criteria in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting

I am new to Spring3 and Hibernate the following code works great but I am trying to find a way to have my list returned in sort order by the date field. Can someone please show me how to add sort to this code

```
// To get list of all articles
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Friend> listFriends(String rUser) 
{
   Friend friend = new Friend();
    friend.setUsername(rUser);

    return (List<Friend>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
       .createCriteria(Friend.class)
        .add(Example.create(friend))
        .list();
}
```

Answer (score 34):

```
.addOrder( Order.desc("date") )
```

Check the [examples in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Either have the database do it or Java, your choice.  Here's how to do it in Java:

```
List<Friend> friends = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
       .createCriteria(Friend.class)
        .add(Example.create(friend))
        .list();
Collections.sort(friends); 

return friends;
```